# WCF service method as WF activity

Tags: c#, wcf, workflow-foundation

I am trying to use WCF service method in Windows Workflow. It was working fine before but all of sudden getting the following error:

The activity 'Send' with OperationName='GetTaskById' must specify either the Endpoint or EndpointConfigurationName property.

Added WCF service reference in WF project library

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITaskService" />
<endpoint address="http://localhost:59137/Tasks.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITaskService" contract="TasksService.ITaskService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ITaskService" />
```